# Is there an Upanishad called Panchakshari Upanishad?

Tags: vedas, upanishads

Came across this on the Internet: [Link](https://www.hithokthi.com/viewstotra.php?g_id=1&cat_id=0&story_id=62#.UnTxJMDCLPU.blogger)

Never heard of this before.  Which Veda has this Upanishad?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because forum is not for determining the purported veracity of youtube videos.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda. Your statement is true but just think if its applicable to above. Scriptures say to become no mind but that doesn't mean we should not use mind

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I have removed the YouTube video and added a website link instead. :)